# Why is Leaflet's choroplet tutorial map not working on cellphone?

Tags: javascript, html, json, leaflet, choropleth

I'm building a choroplet map using the choroplet tutorial on Leaflet: https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/example.html

It works perfectly on desktop but is not working on my cellphone. I'm on Firefox (Android) and I can't do any mouse hover and when clicking on a State it zooms instead of showing the mouse hover. Totally not working. How can I fix it?

Comment: It's **behaviour as expected**. A touchscreen never triggers `mouseover` events, so creating an interaction that depends solely on `mouseover`/`mouseout` will create a sub-par experience on touchscreen devices. Note that you can connect a mouse via an USB OTG cable; don't think that a touchscreen means *only* a touchscreen. Do watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBdQkhm1DvI and consider using `PointerEvent`s checking their `pointerType` property.

Comment: How can I make it working.. or make it better for cell phones? Not sure how to use PointerEvent

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing would be to use the click event. It works with the example.